# What is/are the correct preposition/s to use with "Sicherheit"?

Tags: grammar, preposition

I cannot put my finger on why one of the following examples sounds right while the other sounds wrong:

> a) Der neue Reifen bietet Sicherheit vor Aquaplaning.
>
> b) Ein Deich bietet Sicherheit vor dem Hochwasser.

Sadly, after thinking about this for 15 Minutes and writing the question down, now both sound kind of correct - still, I'm not sure if I can trust myself here, so input would be much appreciated.

Am I just not used to this structure?

Comment: Mit Sicherheit sollte man *"Sicherheit"* bei Unsicherheit nicht benutzen :D - Schöne Frage!

Comment: +1 für einen gleichzeitig weisen *und* bestechend schön formulierten Rat! :)

Comment: Beide Sätze klingen sauber. Ich sehe überhaupt kein Problem damit. Ich rate mal, dass der erste Satz deiner Meinung nach merkwürdig klingt? Das liegt daran, dass Sicherheit das falsche Wort ist ;)

Comment: Je nachdem WAS du ausdrücken willst, kannst du sagen "bietet Sicherheit bei Aquaplaning", wobei ich nicht denke, dass es das ist, was du hier sagen willst.

Comment: @Em1: Lol, nein - ich hätte es sowieso anders ausgedrückt. Beide Sätze sind Beispiele, die nicht von mir stammen. Mir geht's tatsächlich nur darum, ob ich spinne, oder ob es anderen ähnlich geht wie mir (und wenn ja, ob es eine Begründung dafür gibt, die mir entgeht). Dein erster Kommentar ist also schon eine Antwort auf meine Frage :)

Comment: Der zweite Satz klingt für mich unrund, denn ich frage mich bei "dem Hochwasser" "welchem"? `... bietet Sicherheit vor Hochwasser` ist die allgemeingültige Formulierung, aber in einer Konversatation, wenn jmd. auf ein bestimmtes, drohendes Hochwasser hinweist, beispielsweise weil es seit Tagen regnet und flussaufwärts ist das Hochwasser schon da - aber halt, das ist dann ein Damm, und Deich gibt's nur am Meer, oder? So oder so würde ich dann aber auch einen bestimmten Deich erwarten. Fragen Sie Deichgraf Hauke Wattenschlick und Kurverwalter Mövenpick. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Satz b enthält einen Fehler. Da steht:

> b) Ein Deich bietet Sicherheit vor dem Hochwasser.

Der Deich bietet aber hoffentlich nicht nur Sicherheit vor dem einen bestimmten Hochwasser, das möglicherweise am 18. Juli 2023 kommt (oder vor einem anderen bestimmten Hochwasser), sondern generell vor (fast) jedem Hochwasser. Er bietet also nicht "vor *dem* Hochwasser" Sicherheit, sondern "vor Hochwasser" (ohne "dem").
Richtig wäre also:

> b) Ein Deich bietet Sicherheit vor Hochwasser.

Doch sehen wir mal von dieser Kleinigkeit ab:

Beide Sätze folgen demselben Schema:

> [ein Gegenstand] bietet Sicherheit vor [einer Gefahr].

Da beide Sätze demselben Schema folgen, sind beide gleich richtig bzw. gleich falsch. Ich würde aber in diesem Schema den Ausdruck "bietet Sicherheit vor" durch "schützt vor", oder noch besser "verhindert" ersetzen:

> [ein Gegenstand] verhindert [eine Gefahr].
>
> Der neue Reifen verhindert Aquaplaning.
>   Ein Deich verhindert Hochwasser.

Comment: Bis auf den letzten Satz voll einverstanden. Man spricht aber, egal ob der Deich hält oder nicht, von Hochwasser, m.a.W.: ein Deich verhindert dieses nicht. `Ein Deich bietet Sicherheit bei Hochwasser` wäre noch eine Alternative.

Comment: Und auch der vorletzte Satz ist nicht ganz richtig, wie ich es in meiner Antwort versucht habe zu erkläern. Der Reifen verhindert kein Aquaplaning, er verringert nur das Risiko, dass Aquaplaning auftritt.

Comment: Bin mir zwar ebenfalls wegen des letzten Satzes nicht sicher, finde aber das mit dem Schema eine praktische Antwort :) - darum: angenommen!

Comment: @Em1: Wenn man das Risiko des Auftretens einer Gefahr verringert, verhindert man damit in vielen Fällen, dass die Gefahr auftritt. Ich schalt mal in den Pedanterie-Modus: Ein Deich kann ein Hochwasser überhaupt nicht beeinflussen. Ein Deich erfüllt seinen Zweck ja erst wenn ein Hochwasser bereits aufgetreten ist. Ein Deich verhindert eine Überschwemmung des Hinterlandes falls das Hochwasser nicht zu hoch ist. Der Reifen hingegen hat auch ohne Aquaplaning einen Zweck, und ein neuer Reifen mit tiefem Profil kann das Auftreten von Aquaplaning in mehr Fällen verhindern als ein abgefahrener Reifen.

Comment: Hoffentlich bietet der Deich nicht nur *vor* dem Hochwasser Sicherheit, sondern insbesondere auch *während* des Hochwassers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for a short answer:

both versions are fine... using the definite article does refer to one high tide in particular. That is not necessarily wrong though... suppose a high tide has been announced and you quickly build a dam as your house is near the river... then this dam has been built for that very high tide and the sentence is correct.